# CPU and GPU operations parallelization

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have an application that has 3 main functionalities which are running sequentially at the moment:

**1)** Loading data to memory and perform preprocesssing on it.

**2)** Perform some computations on the data using GPU with theano.

**3)** Monitor the state of the computations on GPU and print them to the screen.

These 3 functionalities are embarrassingly parallelizable by using multi-threading. But in python I perform all these three functionalities sequentially. Partly because in the past I had some bad luck with Python multi-threading and GIL issues.

Here in this case, I don't necessarily need to utilize the full-capabilities of multiple-cpu's at hand. All I want to do is, to load the data and preprocess them while the computations at the GPU are performed and monitor the state of the computations at the same time. Currently most time-consuming computations are performed at 2), so I'm kind of time-bounded with operations at 2). Now my questions are:

*Can python parallelize these 3 operations without creating new bottlenecks, e.g.: due to GIL issues.

*Should I use multiprocessing instead of multithreading?

In a nutshell how should parallelize these three operations if I should in Python.

It is been some time since last time I wrote multi-threaded code for CPU(especially for python), any guidance will be appreciated.

Edit: Typos.

Comment: http://nvidianews.nvidia.com/Releases/GPU-Accelerated-Computing-Reaches-Next-Generation-of-Programmers-With-Python-Support-of-NVIDIA-CUDA-950.aspx

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am facing the exact same problem, except in my case, the most costly step is "loading the data". If you have some solution, I would appreciate you posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GIL is a bit of a nuisance sometimes...

A lot of it is going to revolve around how you can use the GPU. Does the API your using allow you to set it running then go off and do something else, occasionally polling to see if the GPU has finished? Or maybe it can raise an event, call a callback or something like that?

I'm sensing from your question that the answer is no... In which case I suspect your only choice (given that you're using Python) is multi processing. If the answer is yes then you can start off the GPU then get on with some preprocessing and plotting in the meantime and then check to see if the GPU has finished.

I don't know much about Python or how it does multiprocessing, but I suspect that it involves serialisation and copying of data being sent between processes. If the quantity of data you're processing is large (I suggest getting worried at the 100's of megabytes mark. Though that's just a hunch) then you may wish to consider how much time is lost in serialising and copy that data. If you don't like the answers to that analysis then your probably out of luck so far as using Python is concerned.

You say that the most time consuming part is the GPU processing? Presumably the other two parts are reasonably lengthy otherwise there would be little point trying to parallelise them. For example if the GPU was 95% of the runtime then saving 5% by parallelising the rest hardly seems worth it.

Comment: yes you are right, the framework I'm using doesn't support polling to see if the GPU has finished at the moment (but they told me that they plan to support in the future, that's in their agenda). Seems like multiprocessing is the best option for me.